# Why do I get a "borrowed data escapes outside of method" error?

Tags: loops, rust, reference, borrow-checker, mutable

I have a variable `renderer` that I have to edit over an event loop. The issue is that I keep getting the same `borrowed data escapes outside of method` error for the event loop in the `run` function of my `App` struct. How do I fix this with still being able to adjust the values of `renderer` over runtime? All the solutions I've seen resulted in some form of copy being passed, which is not what I need. Thanks for the help!

Full error:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method
  --> src/app.rs:54:9
   |
50 |       pub fn run(mut self, renderer: &mut Renderer) -> Result<(), pixels::Error> {
   |                            --------  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
   |                            |
   |                            `renderer` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
...
54 | /         self.event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
55 | |             if let Event::RedrawRequested(_) = event {
56 | |
57 | |                 let current_frame_time = Instant::now();
...  |
84 | |             }
85 | |         });
   | |          ^
   | |          |
   | |__________`renderer` escapes the method body here
   |            argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

For the full, long code, here is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/KGL8/RayTracingPaper/tree/working_snapshot

Shortened version of my App.rs:

```
pub struct App {
    // ***
}

impl App {
    pub fn new() -> Result<Self, pixels::Error> {
        // ***
    }

    pub fn create_window(event_loop: &EventLoop<()>) -> Window {
        // ***
    }

    pub fn run(mut self, renderer: &mut Renderer) -> Result<(), pixels::Error> {

        let mut previous_frame_time = Instant::now();

        self.event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
            if let Event::RedrawRequested(_) = event {

                let current_frame_time = Instant::now();
                let timestep = current_frame_time.duration_since(previous_frame_time).as_secs_f32();
                previous_frame_time = current_frame_time;
                renderer.on_update(timestep, &self.input);

                if let Err(err) = renderer.render(&mut self.pixels) {
                    log_error("renderer.draw_frame", err);
                    *control_flow = ControlFlow::Exit;
                    return;
                }
            }

            // ***

                self.window.request_redraw();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without the full error message but I'm guessing the closure you pass to `event_loop.run` isn't allowed to borrow any data so it can't use `renderer` because it's a reference. How to fix this somewhat depends on why you pass the renderer by reference and not by value in the first place. `event_loop.run` never returns so I'm unsure if there's a benefit to not giving it ownership of `renderer`.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ownership stuff... I'm new to programming. Currently the renderer is declared in my main function and is passed to the app struct:

`let mut renderer = Renderer::new(window, camera);` =>
`app.run(&mut renderer)?;`

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `renderer`, which is a mutable reference, into `event_loop.run`, which is closure with a `'static` lifetime.

Let's look at the [source](https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/blob/924f3323b56190ef93829af080fcca046c19bc80/src/event_loop.rs#L304) for `EventLoop::run`

```
    pub fn run<F>(self, event_handler: F) -> !
    where
        F: 'static + FnMut(Event<'_, T>, [ ... ] ),
```

The `'static + FnMut` part means "this argument is a closure with a static lifetime". To break it down a bit:

- a closure is a lot like function, but it's "bundled together" with all other variables needed to call the function
- `'static` is a special lifetime bound, it tells rust our closure will not borrow any data with non-`'static` lifetime

Since the event loop wants to call the `event_handler` indefinitely, `event_handler` has to continue to exist as long as the program is running.
You correctly used a `move` closure, which causes all the variables referred to in your closure to be captured and moved into the closure (that's the "bundling" above). `renderer` is problematic, because it's a reference, so we can't move it into the closure.

We have a closure that has to live until the program ends, yet includes a reference that will die as soon as the program ends! This is what the compiler means by `borrowed data escapes outside of method`.

To solve this, we need to **promise the compiler that `renderer` will stick around** until the program exits. Easiest way is to make it `'static`,
In `App::run()`

```
pub fn run(mut self, renderer: &'static mut Renderer)
```

then, when you instantiate `Renderer`, use [lazy_static](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/):

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref RENDERER: Renderer = Renderer::new();
}
```

Comment: `’static` does *not* mean that the data lives for the duration of the program. That’s a common misconception that you can find [here](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program). It means that the data doesn’t borrow anything that does not have a `'static` lifetime.

Comment: TIL! appreciate the correction